# JSON.parse not working on older mobile browsers

Tags: php, javascript, android, html, json

I have a JSON string A. A is in the format:

```
'[{"key1":"val1",...,"keyn":"valn"},{...},...,{...}]'
```

A is created on a php server using json_encode(Array).

var str = JSON.parse(A); works in all desktop browsers, mobile safari, mobile chrome etc..

var str = JSON.parse(A); throws an exception('exception: cannot parse string') in Android 2.2 default browser and black berry devices' browers.

JSON.parse works in the browser just not with my JSON string A.  Is there a bug in the json parser on this browser?

edit.
If I put A into a textArea and copy and paste the string directly into the javascript code.. JSON.parse('[{"key1":"val1",...,"keyn":"valn"},{...},...,{...}]') works.

But, this doesn't work -> JSON.parse($('div').html(A).text());

Comment: character set is utf8

Comment: I used utf8_decode(A) in php before the JSON string is sent to the client and it didn't solve it.

Comment: When I type "Android 2.2 json cannot parse string" into Google, the first page of results are all questions asked here on Stack overflow - have you read any of them?

Comment: That did not help.  And to clarify, this is an issue in Javascript, on a browser in Android 2.2 and it also happens on Blackberry devices.

Comment: @symcbean: None of them are about JS.

Answer (score 1):

the older JSON.parse only will parse a object....

try surround like below...

```
'{ "data" : [{"key1":"val1",...,"keyn":"valn"},{...},...,{...}] }'
```

if not work... you can try

```
function getObj(json){
  return (new Function(" return (" + json + "); "))();
}

var value = getObj('[{"key1":"val1",...,"keyn":"valn"},{...},...,{...}]');
```

Comment: ok I'll try that. Is this a known issue?  Is it explained somewhere?

Comment: the new Function create a dynamic function, and you will return the object

Comment: This didn't work either.  It threw an exception "syntaxError: parse error"

Comment: can you add the json string generated? to help us understand the reason of error?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36427/discussion-between-luan-castro-and-francis-snipe)

Comment: [{"1":"u8tk","2":"90650","3":"212261","4":"yoe8","5":"46.65594","6":"90.3781","7":"3ko4n","8":"2013-08-28","9":"aasd","10":"1","11":"0.06895843620315048","12":"2013-08-28"},{"1":"btub","2":"56339","3":"aaa56339","4":"f3io","5":"49.649","6":"-59.19","7":"f3io","8":"2030-01-01","9":" ","10":"3","11":"2.015198728083818","12":"2030-01-01"},{"1":"zz9q","2":"66971","3":"aaa66971","4":"3vvc","5":"43.26","6":"-79.36","7":"3vvc","8":"2030-01-01","9":" ","10":"3","11":"2.0183533795","12":"2030-01-01"}]';

Comment: in third object of json, the index 9 has a problem, the "9["] the last " has a encode error.

Comment: ok.  I'm not sure what that means.  Is the '"' a multi-byte char?

Comment: yes, try change the method of json generation and not use multi-byte char :D maybe json_encode

Answer (score 0):

try:

var myJSON = eval( yourJSONString );